# selenium in python is skipping articles while trying to scrape the data

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

Im trying to extract data from articles using selenium in python, the code is identifying the articles but while running the loop a few articles are skipped randomly. Any help resolving this issue will be appreciated.

```
#Importing libraries
import requests
import os
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import time
import requests
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import traceback
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  

#opening a chrome instance
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:/selenium/chromedriver.exe")

#getting into the website
driver.get('https://academic.oup.com/rof/issue/2/2')

#getting the articles
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/main/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/h5')))

#loop to get in and out of articles
for article in articles:
    try:
        ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(article).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        window1 = driver.window_handles[1]
        driver.switch_to_window(window1)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to_window(window0)
    except:
        print("couldnt get the article")
```

Comment: This may seem a little simplistic but have you tried to increase the wait time per click ? 10 seconds may not be enough to open up the article. Can't see anything too drastically wrong with your code.

Comment: It may be worth reducing the length of your XPATH selector. 
(By.XPATH, '//h5[@class="customLink item-title"]') which is abit more cleaner. Having looked at the selector are you sure the h5 is what you want to click and not the <a> which is the direct child ?

Comment: @AaronS i have tried increasing the wait time but it didnt work. and yes using the xpath you suggested made the code look a bit clean. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`First`**, for collect all article element, you can use this css selector:

```
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.customLink.item-title a')))
```

**`Second`**, This is wrong method:

```
driver.switch_to_window(window1)
```

It's should:

```
driver.switch_to.window(window1)
```

See the difference between **`_`** and **`.`** above.

**`Third`**, you forgot to initialize the `window0` variable:

```
window0 = driver.window_handles[0]
```

And finally, try the following code:

```
#getting into the website
driver.get('https://academic.oup.com/rof/issue/2/2')

#getting the articles
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.customLink.item-title a')))

#loop to get in and out of articles
for article in articles:
    try:
        ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(article).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        window1 = driver.window_handles[1]
        driver.switch_to.window(window1)
        driver.close()
        window0 = driver.window_handles[0]
        driver.switch_to.window(window0)
    except:
        print("couldnt get the article")

driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks it worked. im an amateur in the scraping field so could spare a few seconds and let me know whats the difference between switch_to_window and switch_to.window

Comment: @VenuBhaskar glad it worked, actually I can't found `switch_to_window` method in selenium using python so far. I think that's the wrong method.